# Python - Data model - Subclass Vs Instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For user-defined type `X`,

```
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> issubclass(X, object)    # User-defined type
True
>>> isinstance(X, object)    # User-defined type
True
```

Q) How `X` behaves as both sub class and instance of `object`?

---

```
>>> issubclass(int, object)  # Built-in type
True
>>> isinstance(int, object)  # Built-in type
True
```

Q) How `int` behave as both sub class and instance of `object`?

---

```
>>> issubclass(type, object)  # Meta class
True
>>> isinstance(type, object)  # Meta class
True
```

Q) How `type` can be both, sub class and instance of `object`?

---

```
>>> issubclass(object, type)
False
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
```

`object` not being sub class but instance of `type`, which makes sense

```
>>> issubclass(int, type)
False
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True
>>>
```

`int` not being sub class but instance of `type`, makes sense.

```
>>> issubclass(X, type)      # User-defined type
False
>>> isinstance(X, type)      # User-defined type
True
```

also makes sense.

**Edit:**

[here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) it says, *The major motivation for introducing new-style classes is to provide a unified object model with a full meta-model.*

**Q)** How to understand the meaning of *unified object model*?

**Q)** What is *meta-model*?

**Q)** What does it mean to say, `type` instance of `type`?

Comment: Challenge: create an object/class/whatever `x` where `isinstance(x, object)` evaluates to False.

Comment: Note that `isinstance(int, object)` returning True doesn't _necessarily_ imply that int instances are also object instances. `isinstance(str, str)` returns False.

Comment: @Kevin Looks Impossible to create `x` where `isinstance(x, object)` is False, as per above observation in the query

Comment: It is impossible afaik. You can only alter the behavior of `isinstance`/`issubclass` with a custom meta that has `__instancecheck__` or `__subclasscheck__` defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be easier to understand diagramatically:

[image]

I'm using a red arrow from A to B to mean `A.__class__ == B`, and a black arrow to mean `B in A.__bases__`. Every object in python must have a red arrow, but only instances of `type` have a black arrow.

Roughly speaking

- `issubclass(x, y)` means *"start at x, follow black arrows until you reach `y`"*
- `isinstance(x, y)` means *"start at x, follow one red arrow, and then apply `issubclass`"*

---

Edit: Another example with metaclasses:

```
class MetaClass(type): pass
class MClass(metaclass=MetaClass): pass
class Class(object): pass
c = MClass()
```

[image][<sup>source</sup>](https://gist.github.com/eric-wieser/5fa327c7b57130ce899526092851c742)

Comment: Probably you could have added `X` rather than `float`. The diagram would be complete

Comment: `type` is an instance of `type` does not look obvious

Comment: I chose `float` not `X` because there was an easy example of an instance of a float.

Comment: In the above diagram, `mc=MClass()` & `c=Class()`. isn't it? Not sure, what does `c=MClass()` mean in your answer?

Answer (score 6):

All three of your questions come down to "how can X be both a subclass and instance of `object`". The answer is simple: *everything* is a subclass of `object`. Classes are objects (=instances of `object`), and hence, subclasses (including subclasses of `object`) are also instances of `object`.

Comment: Value add, from saying, classes are objects? In python,why do we have the necessity/advantage to call classes as objects?

Comment: In python-2.x old-style classes `class X: pass` aren't subclasses of `object` (they are still instances of `object` though. In python the phrase: "Everything is an object" is literally True).

Comment: @MSeifert: True. However, OP is explicitly subclassing off of `object`.

Comment: @acdr I was just adressing the "why do we have the necessity/advantage to call classes as objects?" question. Your answer is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @overexchange: The advantage of classes being objects is that you can pass them around. I can make a function which takes as input a class, and returns a different class.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Python is an object and `isinstance(whatever, object) == True` is just a way of saying this. Therefore regular objects and any types are instances of object by design. Some classes inherits object to provide additional functionality (in Py3k all of them, really), for example `type` is a subclass of `object` that yields another types as instances and, say, `Int` is a subclass of `type` (and `object`) that tailored for instantiation integers.
So you might ask - why there is a python object `object`, why this is even a thing that you can pass around and so on. The answer is - `mro`, dude. It turns out that type `object` provides a set of handy descriptors, that are invoked as defaults for a ton of other types (since types ultimately inherit majority of functionality from `object`).